# Seeking equivalent of ArcGIS Pro Summarize Within in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have two polygon layers : "Building foortprints" and "Building buffer" (which is 
a buffer around each building and they do overlap each other). I want to calculate the sum area of all buildings in each buffer. I tried to use Summarized Within tool in ArcGIS Pro, but it gives me error 99999. I guess because the buffers overlaps, it cannot run the tool succesfully.

Is there any way that I can do this calculation in QGIS?

For example in the below image, for each building's buffer I should have the sum of three other buildings area.

[image]

Comment: Personally, I would try and figure out why you are getting an ERROR 999999 from ArcGIS Pro, because I think this should be a trivial task for that software.  Before this question gets any answers you could revise it heavily to ask that instead.  Once  it has an answer for QGIS, then to ask about the ArcGIS Pro error will need another question.

Comment: Indeed, this seems like an XY Problem, where the real question is Why do I receive a 99999 ERROR from Pro?

Comment: Are your buffers saved as polygons or lines? Can you confirm they're saved as polygons?

Comment: If they're polygons and it's still not working, you can use the Join Attributes by Location > Data Management tool and use the Summary of Intersection Features tool (I think there's a count option.)

Comment: This is most likely why: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311174/arcpy-summarizewithin-analysis-error-error-in-executing-tool/359322#359322